# Site not valid - but it is

Tags: facebook, url, dns

So, I'm building a website called "dagbok.nu", which is swedish for "diary now" :)

Anyway, when creating the Facebook application, it claims that the site URL is invalid as well as the app domain. For site url, I used "http://dagbok.nu" and for site domain, I used "dagbok.nu". Please don't reply (as I've seen others do on similar issues) that I should type the site url with the scheme and the domain without - that's exactly what I'm doing.

Right, so according to another question here, one could trouble shoot this functionality using FB's own URL scraper, so I did just that:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdagbok.nu

And the reply: Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped
Right, so now I can assume that the reason for it being considered invalid is because of FB not being able to scrape the URL. But why?

According to [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9100115/site-url-is-not-a-valid-url), one of the reasons seems to be that FB has deemed the URL insecure or "spammy". I've acquired this domain from a previous owner so this wasn't all that impossible. But when doing the same thing as Matthew in that post - i.e. trying to post in my timeline using the domain "http://dagbok.nu", I didn't get any information. The status box expanded as if to include a thumbnail and information about the link, but it only contained a "(No title)" text and nothing more. [image: Screengrab]

So now I don't know what to do. I've tried to check the DIG and NS records from multiple servers around the web, and everyone seems to resolve it correctly, and I've had friends double check the URL from the states as well. I can't understand what's wrong and I have no idea how to ask someone at FB how to resolve this. Does anyone here have a good advice for this? Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT**
When changing the domain to another domain that points to the exact same web server and document_root, it works! So this is definitely a problem with the domain "dagbok.nu" and not with the code on that page.

**EDIT**
When using the debug function above - I see no activity in the server log what so ever. Facebook doesn't even contact the server. When using the alternate url - the one from the last edit, it pops up in the logs as it should.

**EDIT**
I filed a [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/455103071170761) with Facebook, And their first response was that they were going to follow up. Now, a month later, I got an email that said "We are prioritizing bugs based on impact to the developer community. As this bug report has not received much attention from other developers, we are closing it so as to better focus on the top issues", and then they told me to go here to stackoverflow to try to solve my issue - but the issue is WITH THEM, and of course no one else have reported that my site doesn't work, it affects only me, and I haven't opened it yet due to this bug!

**EDIT**
I wanted to file a new bug report, but I can't even that now, since they are blocking bug reports with this URL as well!

I had to edit the URL - [here is the](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/527265697329693) new bug report

Comment: Its very possible that Facebook blocked that domain in their own DNS servers. Can you try any other .nu domains to see if that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, other .nu domains works just fine. If I'm blocked for whatever reason, how would I go about inquiring Facebook about that?

Comment: Did you file a bug report with Facebook http://facebook.com/bugs/create? This sounds like an internal problem of theirs. Your url isn't showing up in any URIBL databases, so it shouldn't be marked as spem. Facebook just seems not to know what to do with it.

Comment: Did you ever try to refence a very simple static HTML on that server, that, like, only includes the necessary HTML tags?

Comment: I bet, it has something to do with your HTML or server configuration on the main page. Another URL on your domain works on the scraper: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdagbok.nu%2Fmember%2Ffeed Check for Character-coding, HTML validity and stuff as supposed by others

Answer (score 6):

When Facebook tries to scrap your site for information, they send a call to your server with specific user agent called "[facebookexternalhit](https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"...

> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date.  The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like  button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter.  Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs -
>   it will look at "Expires" and  "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1(+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

1. Make sure it is not blocked by your server firewall
2. Look in your server log if it even tried to access your site
3. If you think this is a firewall issue look at this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper)

Comment: As described in the issue (second EDIT), there is no connection to my server from Facebook when using the debug tools.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem appears to be with your character encoding string. Your Apache server is currently sending the unsupported string `latin1`. You've defined your `meta:content-type` as `iso-8859-1`. See the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=dagbok.nu&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

From what I've seen, the Facebook parser will stop immediately if it encounters either an [unrecognized character encoding string](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12321015/could-not-retrieve-data-from-url/12321244#12321244) or a [mismatch in character encoding strings](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12320890/facebook-lint-error-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url/12321378#12321378) between your header and meta tags.

The problem could be originating from either your `httpd.conf` or `php.ini` files. Change these to match your `meta` and restart Apache. Since the problem seems to be domain-specific, I'd check `httpd.conf` first.

Comment: A good theory, but if you read my OP, I wrote this: "When using the debug function above - I see no activity in the server log what so ever. Facebook doesn't even contact the server" - So the character encoding couldn't possibly be a factor.

Comment: With the mismatch and the invalid encoding string your html is invalid. That is reason enough to fix this problem and retest. You haven't yet. Facebook may not be checking it because of a cache somewhere that may or may not be maintained by you or Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Could your domain be blacklisted? Could you try messaging your url to someone, and see if Facebook gives you a "This message contains blocked content..." error?

For example:

[image: Message Failed box]

Comment: In my original post there is a screenshot of me trying to add the URL to a status update - as you can see - nothing is returned

Comment: Tried it. Your site is actually blacklisted by facebook, which could be one of the causes of your problems.

I had this once with a hoster provided redirection. (It used the hoster subdomain, and I guess one of the other websites using this subdomain did nasty things :))

Comment: Yes, this has been my assumption - how do I unblock it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide certain minimum Facebook markup on your page, it will respond with "Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped." I only looked at the homepage, but it appears that dagbok.nu contains no Facebook markup. I'm not sure what things must be present at minimum, but in my implementation, I assume the fb:app_id meta tag and the JavaScript SDK script must be there. You may want to take a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins , particularly the Authentication section.

I discovered your question because I had this same error today for an unknown reason. I found that it was caused because the content of my og:image meta tag used an incorrect URL to the image I was trying to use. So as you add Facebook markup to your page, make sure your values are correct or you may continue to receive this message.

Comment: No, I am trying to set the Site URL, not "App on Facebook" url. It works when I use other URL's that doesn't have any FB code on it either. It must be the scraper that somehow refuses to talk to my web page and I don't know why. I have used the exact same steps to add other pages, but this domain is the only one not working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a Facebook problem if you take a look at what I've discovered.

The results when testing it with **[W3C Online Validation Tool](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=dagbok.nu%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3)** are 1 of 2 results.

Tested using: **dagbok.nu** but note **http://dagbok.nu** has no difference in test results. Remove the last forward slash in between tests.

**Test:** 1
**Results:** 72 Errors 0 Warning
**Note:** Shown here is a fragment of the source **Frameset** DOCTYPE webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<NOSCRIPT><IMG SRC="http://svs.bystorm.se/rv?java=off"></NOSCRIPT><SCRIPT SRC="http://svs.bystorm.se/rvj"></SCRIPT>
<HTML STYLE="height:100%;">
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
```

**Test:** 2
**Results:** 4 Errors 1 Warning
**Note:** Shown here is a fragment of the source **Transitional** DOCTYPE webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<title>Dagbok: Framsida</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="author" content="Jonas Eklundh Communication (http://jonas.eklundh.com)">
<meta name="author-email" content="jonas@eklundh.com">
<meta name="copyright" content="Jonas Eklundh Communication @2012">
<meta name="keywords" content="Atlas,Inneh&aring;llssystem,Jonas Eklundh">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="creation-time" content="0,079s">
<meta name="kort" content="DGB">
```

Repeated tests loop these results when done a couple seconds apart indicating a page-redirect is occurring.

**Security warnings** are seen in Firefox and Chrome when visiting your site using these secure URL's:
https://dagbok.nu
https://www.dagbok.nu

The browser indicates the site should not be trusted because it's impersonating another site using invalid security certificate from ***.loopiasecure.com**

**Recommendation:** Check your .htaccess file, CMS Settings, page redirection, and security settings. Use the above source webpages to realize those file-locations / file-names that are being served to discover what's set incorrectly.

Once that's done, I think Facebook will be happy to then debug your webpage and provide additional recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately, there was some problems with my registrar so the site pointed to a different DNS for a while, which may have led to the symptoms you're seeing there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and I discovered it was an incorrect IPv6 address in the AAAA records for my domain. The IPv4 record was correct, so the site worked in a browser but FB obviously check the IPv6 records!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may also happen when Cloudflare is used. This is because Cloudflare protects the page from Facebook, which is then unable to collect the data, which in turn makes Facebook think the page is invalid.

My fix was:

1. Turn off Cloudflare for the page.
2. Scrape the page using Facebook's Dev Tools: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object
3. Click and let run the "Fetch new scrape information" button.
4. Re-enable cloudflare protection for the page.

You should then be able to continue to add the page where you needed.